# SQL: Dynamic Round

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

I would like to round values resulting from my SQL statement, but dynamically.

I actually forgot the official term for this, but you might understand it using this explanation:

```
129.12144214 --> 129
0.000052142124 --> 0.0000521
2.213131 --> 2.21
```

The amount of nonzero decimals, in this case, is of course 3.

How would I be able to do this in SQL?

Comment: everything is possible in SQL!^^ could you explain the logic a bit more detailed? why do you expect 129 and not 129.121?

Comment: Just fixed a mistake in the examples... Well, I just want the three first nonzero values and nothing behind them.

Comment: What is the expected result of 5001.123 ?  And of 0.01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following these steps you should get the results you desire (example 129.12144214):

- get the log10: 2,11099836751079
- cut the decimals: **2**
- devide your 129,... with (10^**2**): 1.29121442
- round to 2 decimals: 1.29
- multiply with (10^**2**): 129

The idea is to bring every value to a value between 0 and 10, then round to two decimals and then bring him back to his original "range".

In SQL it's something like (ok, i have done it in SQL Server, but the commands should be the same):

```
DECLARE @x decimal(18,6);
SET @x = 129.12144214  ;

SELECT (ROUND(@x / POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG10(@x))), 2)) * POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG10(@x)))
```

Comment: its oracle : select (ROUND(0.000052142124/power(10,floor(log(10,0.000052142124))),2)) * POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG(10,0.000052142124))) as result
 from dual